# ¿Como hallar el valor mas alto dentro de un hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

Bien, el problema es sencillo, tengo que introducir una serie de numeros y almacenarlos en un mapa . Al final tiene que devolver el valor que mas veces esté repetido. Consigo que el mapa guarde los valores pero a la hora de devolverlos no se como hacer para que imprima el valor que mas se repite ( en el codigo la variable veces).

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class AceptaElReto1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        HashMap<String, Integer> numeros = new HashMap<>();
        int casos = sc.nextInt();
        int veces=0;
        String numero;
        while (casos != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < casos; i++) {
                numero = sc.next();
                if (numeros.get(numero) == null) {
                    veces = 1;
                } else {
                    veces = numeros.get(numero) + 1;
                }

                numeros.put(numero, veces); 
            }

            for (String s : numeros.keySet()) {
                System.out.println("s = " + s);
            }
            casos = sc.nextInt();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio aclara, el valor más alto o el más veces repetido en tu titulo, revisa [ask] saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Hola si realmente no interesan las claves de tu mapa, creo que puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
Map<String, Integer> numeros = new HashedMap<>();
   numeros.put("A", 1);
   numeros.put("B", 2);
   numeros.put("C", 2);
   numeros.put("D", 3);    
   numeros.put("F", 2);  

Map<Integer, Integer> frecuencias = new HashedMap<>(numeros.size());        
   for( Integer key : numeros.values()) {
       frecuencias.put(key, Collections.frequency(numeros.values(), key));
   }

Integer max = Collections.max(frecuencias.entrySet(),
Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)).getKey();

assertThat(max,is(2));
```

Comment: Pero esto me duevuelve el numero de veces que el caracter está repetido, yo lo que quiero saber es el caracter que mas veces está repetido, sin importar cuantas veces sean. Muchas gracias aun asi por tu respuesta!!

Comment: frecuencias contiene como clave el elemento y como valor el numero de veces que este se repite, max se encuentra almacenando la clave que tiene valor es mas grande por eso regresa el numero 2 por que 2 es el número que mas veces se repite como valor en tu mapa orginal.